# Is there a way to generate an error event if a signal has no events in the last 24 hours for example?

Tags: serilog, seq

I know there's health check to check specific URLs, but I was wondering if there was a simpler way to setup a signal and have **seq** generate an error if that signal has no entries in the last 24 hours, so that seq not only can notify us of errors via Digest Email app for instance, but also notify us if something like a job failed to run altogether, which would obviously generate no error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seq's [dashboard alerts](https://docs.datalust.co/docs/alerts) can do this. They're based on charts which are configured with a few different parameters.

On the chart's *Signal* tab, choose the signal.

On the chart's *Query* tab:

```
select count(*) as count
from stream
```

And from the *Alerts* tab, an an alert with condition:

```
count = 0
```

over the time range you want to check.